# Why does ruby let me use #$$ to print the PID in a string?

Tags: ruby, pid

I was looking at some code examples and I came across this line:

```
puts "child #$$ accepting..."
```

which outputs

```
>> child 7231 accepting...
```

It looks like $$ is the PID and it's leveraging some shorthand for the normal `#{$$}` string interpolation syntax. I can't find the documentation for this though. I'm curious what other short hand tricks are available (or going to confuse me).

Where are the docs? Why is this special?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby allows you to omit the braces for global (`$var`), instance (`@var`), and class (`@@var`) variables when doing string interpolation.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know that... Awesome!

Comment: Same here, I never knew that!

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those features that I personally avoid using  because I like the consistency of always doing things the same way, but to each their own. =)

Comment: but those extra 2 keystrokes!! :)

Comment: This means `#$$` is equivalent to `#{$$}` but `$$` by itself is not interpolated, then? Interesting.

Comment: "`but those extra 2 keystrokes!!` can translate to hours of debugging time if someone encounters that construct but doesn't know about it. It's cute, it's marginally useful, but it also is not how the majority of Ruby code is written.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree. Reese, got an upvote from me. Just being cheeky :). I mean the fact I had to ask this question proves his point.

Comment: I agree, and also gave an upvote to him. One of the things I keep in mind here is that a lot of less experienced developers see "neat tricks" and equate that to something desirable. Being a studly-programmer in assembler, C and Perl by writing code that is inscrutable might fly in some shops because it's "tight", but I try to take a long-term, holistic view of all code, including those mentioned -- what will work now and down the road. Esoteric knowledge is good but knowing when to use it, and why, is more important. Ruby should be "zen-like", not inscrutable. That's my $0.02.